# WinActor　IE以外のウェブブラウザ（GoogleChrome、Firefox）の動作について

Tags: google-chrome, 画像, rpa

WinActorというRPAを使用しているのですが、
動作環境ウェブブラウザとして、IEバージュン8～11の記載がありますが、
ChromeやFirefoxでの動作は可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

WinActor使ってます！
IEモードの自動記録や、IE関連のライブラリについては、IE限定の機能です。
ChromeやFirefoxについては、画像マッチングやエミュレーション機能によりWinActorの使用が可能です。

https://winactor.com/

に詳しい内容が記載されていましたよ。

Answer (score 1):

『WinActor_操作マニュアル』によると、現段階ではIEモードはIEしか対応できません。
RPAソフト`UiPath`であればChromeやFirefoxに対応できます。